# Most efficient way to download large amounts of files to storage at once?

Tags: android, performance, pdf, asynchronous

Considering that the equipment you have is a low/mid-end android tablet, what would be the most efficient way to download large (let's say hundreds of pdfs) to storage from an internet source?

Would running multiple Asynchronous threads in parallel overload the tablet's hardware capability and actually result in lower performance?

What are the general rules/industry standards for situations like this?

Comment: There are no specific rules, since the hardware AND the connection will be mandatory to choose the best option. Parallel programing will require more CPU and RAM and, depending of the internet connection (and the target website) won't be effective. You must test some scenarios OR give to the user the option to choose mode (1, 2, 4 threads).

Comment: I see. So it seems as though you will just have to test for the specific hardware provided. Thank you.